# Mono for Android - Exception thrown by type initializer System.Data.Services.Client.TypeSystem

Tags: android, linker, mono, xamarin.android

I'm getting an error when running my Mono for Android app

An exception was thrown by the type initializer for System.Data.Services.Client.TypeSystem

If I connect my devices via USB and run the project from visual studio it works fine, but if I create a package, sign it, zipalign it and then install to a fresh devices then it gives this error.

Seems like a linking problem, but I'm not sure. My Release settings for 'Mono Android Options' has linking set to 'Sdk and Assemblies' and the shared runtime is not ticked.

I don't really know what else I need to add here to get a proper answer, so please let me know before voting down!!

Answer (score 0):

It could be the assembly requires stuff (e.g. thru reflection) that the linker removes since it seems unused by the application.

A quick way to test this is to set your project linker behaviour to "Don't link", rebuild and try your application again.

If it starts working then it's a bug (i.e. the linker is missing some exclusions for that assembly) and should be reported to http://bugzilla.xamarin.com

If it still does not work then it's not related to the linker - but it could still be a bug. Try creating a small, self-contained, test case (showing this same issue) and attach it to a bug report.